# Is it a drive path or another? Check with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to check whether it is a drive path or a "pol" path.
For this I have already written a small code, unfortunately, I always return true.

The regex expression may be incorrect `\W?\w{1}:{1}[/]{1}`. How do I do it right?The path names can always be different and do not have to agree with the pole path.
Thank you in advance.

---

```
public bool isPolPath(string path)
{
     bool isPolPath= true;
     // Pol-Path:       /Buy/Toy/Special/Clue
     // drive-Path:     Q:\Buy/Special/Clue  

     Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"\W?\w{1}:{1}[/]{1}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     Match matchSuccess = myRegex.Match(path);
     if (matchSuccess.Success)
         isPolPath= false;

     return isPolPath;
}
```

Comment: what is the rule to distinguish pol or drive path? for given examples of input: `return path.StartsWith("/");`

Comment: To make the question clearer, please provide a set of test cases as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regexes to achieve this. Use `System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot`. It returns `X:\` (where `X` is the actual drive letter) if the given path contains drive letter and an empty string or slash otherwise.

```
new List<string> { 
    @"/Buy/Toy/Special/Clue",
    @"q:\Buy/Special/Clue",
    @"Buy",
    @"/",
    @"\",
    @"q:",
    @"q:/",
    @"q:\",
    //@"",    // This throws an exception saying path is illegal
}.ForEach(
    p => Console.WriteLine(Path.GetPathRoot(p))
);

/* This code outputs:
  \
  q:\

  \
  \
  q:
  q:\
  q:\
*/
```

Therefore your check may look like this:

```
isPolPath = Path.GetPathRoot(path).Length < 2;
```

If you wish to make your code more foolproof and protect from exception when an empty string is passed, you need to decide if an empty (or null) string is a pol-path or drive path. Depending on the decision the check would be either

```
sPolPath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) || Path.GetPathRoot(path).Length < 2;
```

or

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
    sPolPath = false;
else
    sPolPath = Path.GetPathRoot(path).Length < 2;
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for your solution response.